# 'vertically join' php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble finding the right function to rearrange my multidimensional-array. I will explain using an example.

so i have three different arrays, let's say:

```
$ID  (containing n numbers)

$Name (containing n names)

$Explanation (containing n explanations)
```

I have tried array($id, $name, $explanation), which returns a new array, containing the above three arrays as they were before. However I would like to have my new array in the following way:

```
array(
   array (1[0], football[0], played on grass[0])
   array (2[1], swimming[1], played in the water[1])
   array (3[2], diving[2], played under water[2])
   ....
   array (n+1[n], basketball[n], played indoors[n])
)
```

I would like my array this way so it can be processed more easily into my database. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the 3 arrays equal in length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that all the three arrays are equal in length say `$arr1,$arr2,$arr3`, Try:

```
$result = array();
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val){
  $result[] = array($val,$arr2[$key],$arr3[$key]);
}
```

Then for re-indexing result array starting from index 1 you can try like,

```
$result = array_unshift($result,null);
unset($result[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, your assumption was correct. Thanks a lot, works like a charm :)